# find highest value in Map <Object?, Object?>

Tags: dart

I try to resolve the highest value of a Map, with different field names. In this case highestValue should be "Luke"

```
 String? highestValue;
    
 Map<Object?, Object?>? points =
      {
        "Vader": 40,
        "Obi-Wan": 20,
        "Luke": 50,
      };
    
 highestValue = ...
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map is terribly typed so I am not sure what situations we need to take into account here. E.g. what should happen if the value are not an `int`? But I have made the following example of how you could do it:

```dart
void main() {
  String? highestValue;

  Map<Object?, Object?>? points =
  {
    "Vader": 40,
    "Obi-Wan": 20,
    "Luke": 50,
  };

  highestValue = points.entries.reduce((a, b) {
    final aValue = a.value;
    final bValue = b.value;

    if (aValue is! int) {
      return b;
    }

    if (bValue is! int) {
      return a;
    }

    return aValue > bValue ? a : b;
  }).key as String?;

  print(highestValue); // Luke
}
```

But as you can see, a lot of the logic comes from the fact that your map contains `Object?` objects and not a more specific type like `int`.

### Extra solution added after request in comment

If we want to have extract the second biggest, we are starting to get into the territory where it makes more sense to just generate a list and then order it.

So we can do something like this where we do this based on the map:

```dart
void main() {
  String? highestValue;

  Map<Object?, Object?>? points = {
    "Vader": 40,
    "Obi-Wan": 20,
    "Obi-Wan": 20,
    "Luke": 50,
  };

  final sortedEntries = points.entries.toList()
    ..sort((entry1, entry2) {
      final aValue = entry1.value;
      final bValue = entry2.value;

      if (aValue is! int) {
        return 1;
      }

      if (bValue is! int) {
        return -1;
      }

      return bValue.compareTo(aValue);
    });

  sortedEntries
      .forEach((entry) => print('Key: ${entry.key} | Value: ${entry.value}'));
  // Key: Luke | Value: 50
  // Key: Vader | Value: 40
  // Key: Obi-Wan | Value: 20

  String nameOfTheSecondLargest = sortedEntries[1].key as String;
  print(nameOfTheSecondLargest); // Vader
}
```

Comment: works for me, thanks. what would it look like if you wanted the second highest value?

Comment: @Bernhard I would consider creating a list based on your map and sort the list based on the values. I can add such a solution to my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @Bernhard Update answer with example of how you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Map<String, int>? points =
  {
    "Vader": 40,
    "Obi-Wan": 20,
    "Luke": 50,
  };

String highest = points.keys.first;
int max = points.values.first;

points.forEach((key, value) {
  if(max < value){
    max=value;
    highest = key;
  }
});
```

You can do something like this. More easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this :

import:

```
import 'dart:math';
```

then

```
Map<Object?, Object?> points = {
          "Vader": 40,
          "Obi-Wan": 20,
          "Luke": 50,
        };
var highestValue = (points.values.toList().map((e) => e as int).reduce(max));
print(highestValue);
```